# Incorrect query run in BigQuery by Apps Script code

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-apps-script-editor

We have a number of .gs files in an Apps Script project, which schedule a number of BiqQuery SQL queries into tables.

Everything was fine till a few days ago when one table started not updating correctly. We've looked into the query history, and seen that one of our tables hasn't been updated in quite a while. When we run the Apps Script responsible for that table, and check the BigQuery query history, it actually is running a different query, even though the script is valid and references different source and destination tables.

Our scripts mostly look like the below:

```
function table_load_1() {
  var configuration = {
    "query": {
      "useQueryCache": false,
      "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": "project",
        "datasetId": "schema",
        "tableId": "destination_table"
      },
      "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
      "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
      "allowLargeResults": true,
      "useLegacySql": false,
      "query": "select * from `project.schema.source_table` "
    }
  };

  var job = {
    "configuration": configuration
  };

  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, "project");
  Logger.log(jobResult);
}
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: How are you executing the functions? If you use a webapp to run a deployed version, ensure that you have deployed the proper version.

Comment: I recommend to open a support case and share the JobIDs to better investigate. From the information you provided I can recommend to look in the logs using this filter: resource.type="bigquery_resource"
logName="projects/PROJECT_NAME/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access"
protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"
protoPayload.serviceData.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobConfiguration.query.query="select * from `project.schema.source_table`" and compare the JobIDs in the logs with the ones in the job history.